# Why is my AJAX call failing in github pages?

Tags: ajax, api, http-status-code-404, github-pages

On my local end everything works fine but on github pages when I request the ajax call it returns a 404 error. If i delete my github url they put before the call url it works just fine.

Comment: fixed... added dataType: 'json' after get request

Comment: Where's dataType added if using Vanilla JS instead of jQuery?